Seeking Feedback on Data Science Portfolio
I hope you're doing well. I've recently started building my data science portfolio on GitHub with the goal of securing a role as a data scientist. I would greatly appreciate your feedback to help me improve and grow. Here are a few details:
Context: I'm currently in the early stages of developing my portfolio. 
Purpose: My goal is to showcase my data science skills and projects effectively. 
Link to Portfolio: https://github.com/colinlim84/portfolio/blob/main/README.md

Areas I'm Particularly Interested In:
Project Selection: Are the projects relevant and varied enough to demonstrate a range of skills?
Presentation: Is the information presented clearly? Should I include more details or metrics?
Code Quality: Any suggestions on improving the structure, readability, or efficiency of my code?
Overall Impression: What are your general thoughts on the portfolio as it stands?
Your constructive feedback would be invaluable to me as I continue to develop and refine my portfolio. Thank you in advance for your time and input!
Thanks y'all in advance

Ask yourself: who is supposed to be your audience? HR probably is not going to care. So I am guessing some technical person? I suppose this is for an entry position?

Thanks @Make42 for taking time to reply.
Sometimes HR can be technical as well though no extensively. Then, it's also for the hiring manager and eng., so deliverance needs to be both accessible and impressive for HR and technical person.
Yea, probably entry to mid-level. Any thoughts on how it is now?

I speak only from my own experience and the impression I have from the people I have worked with (10 years), so there might be different people around than the ones I know. For the HR people and the management people I know, this is far above their heads and far too technical; they are going to flee as soon as they click the link. Except for the Dashboards, because they are nice to look at. I would send them only the link to one of the Dashboards.

For me (as a Lead Data Scientist) this is very entry level in terms of ML / Data Science. I teach this and more at university in an entry course "Python for Machine Learning" for students of "Marketing Intelligence" (a slightly technical business major) that do not know any programming before we start. After looking at your portfolio, I will think "Ok, he has seen some code and is able to program some stuff." I am not going to assume that you are able to do some real-life complex problem solving (as in Data Science) or application development.

This is no problem though: I might be interested to talk to you and see what else you have to offer or how much your are interested in learning more on the job. At the very least the portfolio shows effort on your part to make a good impression, which is already a lot better than an "I don't care" attitude. --- I hope this helps. Keep in mind, this is a very subjective opinion of mine after taking only 5 min to think about it.

@Make42 Thank you for your thoughtful feedback. Took a while because I wanted to ensure I had thoroughly considered your insights before replying.
I see your point as it being rudimentary. Building on your feedback, I plan to beef it more to impress. I'm thinking of using slightly more advance algo (XGBoost, Multi-layer Perceptrons) with more in-depth training methods (hyper parameter tuning with Bayesian Optimization).

@Make42 Thanks for much for taking the effort to guide me - I truly, truly appreciate it! It's scary to put my portfolio out there to be judge, I really glad the first comments came from you!

Using a different algorithm would not impress me, because you are just copy-pasting. The only benefit would be that you show that you know these exist (which is good though). It does not show me that you know how they work - that you would need to show some other way, e.g., in an interview. Similarly, using a library for hyper-parameter tuning only shows you know that this topic exists (which is good) and that you are able to use a library (which is also good). To show that you know how it works, you would have to program it yourself. But how do I know you did not copy-paste it from some blog?

I understand that this is scary and I commend you for doing so! What I did at some point, I put three - very simply - apps online that the HR person or whoever could actually use. The methods used in the background were very simple. A bit like your dashboards. I think what you are doing is good, but do not overvalue how impressed others will be.

Thanks @Make42 for your kindness and inspiration. I shall attempt


to demonstrate ability to take a complex real-life problem and deliver insight/data products impactful to business


Put out some apps online for HR to play around


